# find() text message.content python discord

Tags: python, text, find, discord

```
if message.content.lower().startswith('add'):
    text_in = message.content
    text_out = text_in[text_in.find("(") + 1:text_in.find(")")]
```

I would like to just write "add 500" instead of typing "add (500)" how would that command be?
If you have a complete answer, I'll put the answer as your best choice.

Comment: Question is not complete, please provide more details!

Comment: Please do not vandalise your posts. Once you have submitted a post, you have licensed the content to the Stack Overflow community at large ([under the CC BY-SA license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's not a great amount of detail in your question, but if we assume that `message.content` contains a string like "add(500)", then your existing code would place the string "500" in `text_out`.

To do the same thing where `message.content` looks like "add 500", you could split `message.content` by whitespace (`.split()`), then inspect the second element (`[1]`):

```
if message.content.lower().startswith('add'):
    text_out = message.content.split()[1]
```